# cross product/ cartesian product in python

Tags: python, pandas, cartesian-product, cross-product

I want to get a cartesian product of dates. I have following dates ( months)  in data set

201801
201802

as an output i want as

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please repeat the [tour] and take the time to re-read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`. Let L be your column `df['dates']` for example -

```
from itertools import product

l = [201801,201802]
out = pd.DataFrame(list(product(l,l)))
print(out)
```

```
        0       1
0  201801  201801
1  201802  201801
2  201801  201802
3  201802  201802
```

---

Or you could simply use a list comprehension to iterate l 2 times.

```
out = pd.DataFrame([(j,i) for i in l for j in l])
print(out)
```

```
        0       1
0  201801  201801
1  201802  201801
2  201801  201802
3  201802  201802
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: this is not a list it is data frame

Comment: you can jsut use `pd.DataFrame` on it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)

Comment: I was searching for same but am not able to figure out, FLAG is the one  I should not :) but what is the correct response should i give for appreciation?

Comment: When you do want to mark and answer, there is an upvote button next to the answer to appreciate the solution, and below that there is a tick mark, which only appears on answers for your questions. Clicking this allows a user to mark the answer that solved their problem. Check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHgYa.png